# Need Help Understanding Javascript Closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I am learning about javascript closures and am having difficulty understanding the concept. If someone would be kind enough to guide me through this example, i.e., where inputs and outputs are going, I'd appreciate it.

```
var hidden = mystery(3);
var jumble = mystery3(hidden);
var result = jumble(2);

function mystery ( input ){
  var secret = 4;
  input+=2;
  function mystery2 ( multiplier ) { 
    multiplier *= input;
    return secret * multiplier;
  }
  return mystery2;
}
function mystery3 ( param ){
  function mystery4 ( bonus ){
    return param(6) + bonus;
  }
  return mystery4;
}
results;
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Agreed that this is a duplicate of the question that @null linked to, although stated with a contrived and hard-to-follow example.

Comment: This is from Code School, I don't understand how the answer was 122 and hoped that someone would show me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's analyze this step by step.

The first call is to `mystery` with an argument of `3`.

What does `mystery` do? It defines a variable `secret` with the value `4` and then it adds `2` to `input`.

So after the first two lines of `mystery`, you have:

```
secret = 4;
input = 5;
```

Then you have a nested function called `mystery2` which takes in an argument called `multiplier`. In the first line it multiplies `input` to `multiplier`, and then returns `secret * multiplier`. We don't know the values of `multiplier`, but we **do** know the values `secret` and `input`. You might be wondering how that is. Well, in JavaScript when you create a closure, it is *lexically bound to the current scope*. This is just a fancy way of saying that the closure "knows" about all local variables that were created in the same scope that the closure *itself* was created. This behavior applies to nested functions as well which is why they can behave as closures in JavaScript. So what this means is that `mystery2`, when it is eventually called, will have `secret` set to `4` and `input` set to `5`. So this `mystery2`, which knows about these two values, is returned from `mystery`. So after execution, the variable `hidden` doesn't contain a value, instead it contains a reference to an instance of `mystery2` where the values of `secret` and `input` are the ones I mentioned earlier.

What is the advantage of this? The advantage is that you can have multiple copies of `mystery2`, which "know" different values of `input` based on what was passed into `mystery`. So here, `mystery` is sort of behaving like a constructor for `mystery2`.

Now we have `hidden` pointing to an instance of `mystery2`. So in this case `hidden` is sort of an alias for our own special copy of `mystery2`.

In the next line, you call `mystery3` and pass in `hidden` as an argument. What happens inside `mystery3`? Well `mystery3` accepts a parameter called `param`, then it does something similar to `mystery`; it returns a function. What does this function do? It accepts a parameter called `bonus`. Then it does `param(6) + bonus`.

What does that mean?

What is `param`? It is the argument that was passed into `mystery3`. Since `mystery4` behaves like a closure, it "knows" about `param`. But *actually*, what is `param`? Well, `param` is `hidden`, which points to our special instance of `mystery2`! Now here is where we *actually* evaluate `mystery2`: we call it with an argument of `6`, which will be the value of `multiplier`. So now you have `multiplier *= input`. The value of `input` that `mystery2` "knows" is `5`. So we basically have `6 * 5`, which means that `multiplier` is now set to `30`. Then we return `secret * multiplier`, which is `4 * 30`, which is `120`. So what this means is that `param(6)` returns `120`, which we then add to `bonus`. Keep in mind that this will happen *only* when we actually execute `mystery4`.

When do we execute `mystery4`? Well after we call `mystery3`, we return a copy of `mystery4`, which is then assigned to `jumble`. After that we call `jumble(2)`. So what is `jumble`? It is essentially this:

```
function mystery4(bonus) {
    return param(6) + bonus
}
```

What is `param`? Well, that is basically `mystery2`:

```
function mystery2 ( multiplier ) { 
    multiplier *= input;
    return secret * multiplier;
}
```

Let's go over the calculations again. When we call `param(6)`, we basically have `multiplier` set to `6` inside `mystery2`. `mystery2` "knows" that `input` is `5` (it is what we calculated inside `mystery`). So `multiplier *= input`, means that `multiplier` is now `30`. Then we do `secret * multiplier`, which is `4 * 30`, which is `120`. So the return value of `param(6)` is `120`. To *this* value we add `bonus` inside `mystery4`. We called `mystery4` with an argument of `2`, so we have `120 + 2`, which means that the final result is `122`.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: No problem! Closures are a little difficult to grasp initially.

Comment: Very nice. it was baffling

Comment: This was the best explanation yet, including those from the Code School site! Thank you so much!!!!